# A word that means to add a small amount of into food (example in body)

Tags: single-word-requests

I am thinking of something like infiltration or adulteration, but for food. For example consider these sentences that should be compatible with the word being sought (as different parts of speech, of course):

> The food at the restaurant tasted so good that it seemed like the chef _______ it with crack.
>
> Even _______ the cake from this recipe with a small additional amount of sugar made it taste too sweet to be palatable.
>
> The cookies were _______ with a small amount of chocolate and this made them absolutely irresistible.

I suppose the word “lace” would work, but I am looking for something with less of a negative connotation.

Comment: Not sure they're far enough from *lacing* but there's *spiking* and *spritzing* and *spicing*.

Comment: I came up with *instilled* and *infused*, as well. Perhaps a synonym of those words that also implied "a small but potent amount of" would work better. Something like *sprinkled*, but that implies that only the outside of the food was affected.

Comment: **a pinch of** or **hint of** as in "the pastry had the *hint* of grated lemon rind"

Comment: @KannE, depends on the context. Perhaps people tend to overdo it with sugar and this is a warning to others from the experience of the person that tried it.

Comment: *Infused* is the closest I've been able to come up with, but it has the connotation that the substance being added is a liquid (?).

Comment: What's wrong with "seasoned" (or "seasoning", in the second case)??

Comment: You said you didn't want to used "laced", but in the first example it seems appropriate and idiomatic to say "laced it with crack". I wouldn't take it as a negative in that context.

Comment: Consider _tinge_ (verb). _OED_ definition: "_transferred._ To impart a slight taste or smell to; to affect slightly by admixture."

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Apologies.  Would you mind pinging me at a better place? // I can't edit there -- would you like to take a stab at rescuing it?

Answer (score 1):

**Enhance, Enhanced**

This means ‘improved’ and can mean ‘added to’.

If you don’t like the result, (ie, it was not ultimately ‘an enhancement’), you can use the form: ‘When the recipe was enhanced with additional sugar, it unfortunately turned out too sweet’. Or ‘when we tried added sugar as a possible enhancement, it became too sweet, or overly sweet’.

Your examples:

- The food at the restaurant tasted so good that it seemed like the chef enhanced it with crack.
- Even enhancing the cake from this recipe with a small additional amount of sugar made it taste too sweet to be palatable.

Or, Enhancing the cake from this recipe with **even** a small additional amount of sugar, made it taste too sweet to be palatable.

- The cookies were enhanced with a small amount of chocolate and this made them absolutely irresistible.

Advantages - a fairly neutral word, does not denote a negative addition like ‘laced’.

Answer (score 1):

In your first and third examples, *seasoned* would work well - "seasoned with crack" would certainly imply that's something's addictive (or chocolate, a habit with which I'm more familiar).

Your second example is actually a little different. Rather than adding a crucial tiny bit of something special as in your other cases, the cake is spoilt by adding an excess of a major ingredient. If it was ruined by the addition of a little black pepper, *seasoned* would still work.

In the first case, *spiked* would also work.

Answer (score 0):

When the substance involved is food, a common word choice for this context is *sprinkle* or more properly, *sprinkling*.

> sprinkling (noun)
>   sprin·​kling | \ ˈspriŋ-kliŋ  \
>   1: a limited
>   quantity or amount : MODICUM
>   2: a small quantity falling in scattered
>   drops or particles
>   3: a small number distributed at random :
>   SCATTERING

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sprinkling

*Sprinkle* does imply that the small amount of added ingredient is dusted or scattered on the surface of the larger item or quantity of food, but is well understood even when the mechanism of applying the ingredient doesn't strictly adhere to the definition.

Comment: See my comment to the question. I thought of this word as well, but without mixing in what was sprinkled, the implication is that only the outside of the food is affected. I am looking for a word that means that the entire volume of the food would contain the substance that was added without necessarily implying how this was done (as is the case with *sprinkled*).

Comment: I see it now; I was probably already typing when you commented.  I think this is a viable and factually correct answer (although maybe not the _best possible_ answer). Although there is an implication of the ingredient being only on the outside if you use a word so closely related to sprinkle, the first definition of 'sprinkling' is just a small quantity or amount with no associated location.

Answer (score 0):

For a positive connotation consider ***augment***
defined by [Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/augment) as:

> Make (something) greater by adding to it; increase

Your sentences become:

> - The food at the restaurant tasted so good that it seemed like the chef *augmented* it with crack.
> - Even *augmenting* the cake from this recipe with a small additional amount sugar made it taste too sweet to be palatable.
> - The cookies were *augmented* with a small amount of chocolate and this made them absolutely irresistible.

Answer (score 0):

For some of your examples, you can

**spice [it up]**

> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/spice): 2. TRANSITIVE VERB
>   If you spice something that you say or do, you add excitement or interest to it.  *They spiced their conversations and discussions with intrigue.*

For example

- The food at the restaurant tasted so good that it seemed like the chef had spiced it up with crack.
- The cookies were spiced with just a bit of chocolate and this made all the difference.

Granted, "spiced" is a little weird in the chocolate example, but as a stretch it could work.  It would work very well with something a bit more unusual in the context, such as *cloves*.  And spicing with chocolate can work great in a savory recipe:

- Inspired by the Mexican traditional recipe for *mole*, I spiced my pot roast with a little bit of cocoa.  Everyone loved it and no one could guess the secret ingredient.  (I did make sure to ask all my guests about allergies, though.)

One more idea:

**give some pizzazz with**

> [pizzazz (American Heritage)](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pizzazz): n. Informal
>   1. Dazzling style; flamboyance; flair.
>   2. Vigorous spirit; energy or excitement.

Example:

- I tried to give the cookies some **pizzazz** by increasing the sugar, but I overdid it and they just tasted saccharine sweet.

Answer (score -1):

Annointed

Which is a word that literally means putting a sacred oil on someone’s head to bless them.

Poetic, and would allow the feeling that the addition of the ingredient makes the cake (or whatever) divine.

Your examples

- The food at the restaurant tasted so good that it seemed like the chef annointed it with crack.
  (This one becomes funny, because of the contrast.
- sugar example - it doesn’t really work for and this example doesn’t make sense to me anyway.
- The cookies were annointed with a small amount of chocolate and this made them absolutely irresistible.
  (Works well as the ‘addition made them heavenly).

Example in use

‘A good quality Greek extra-virgin is my annointing oil of choice’ (for a joint of meat) - Simply Nigella, cookbook, Nigella Lawson